# How can I find $6N^2 + 3NS + S^2 - 21N -61$, without finding N and S itself?

Tags: polynomials

Let $N$ and $S$ be the roots of $A(D) = 5D^2 - 21D - 61$. How can I find $6N^2 + 3NS + S^2 - 21N -61$, without finding N and S itself? 
I know how to get $N^2 + S^2$ from $(N+S)^2 - 2(NS)$ via Vieta's formulas but that's about it, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint : Recall the definition of roots and observe that
$$6N^{2} + 3NS + S^{2} - 21N - 61 = N^{2} + S^{2} + 3NS + (5N^{2} - 21N - 61)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned we can apply:

$(N+S)^2=N^2+S^2+2NS$

$5D^2-21D-61=0$ $\rightarrow D^2-\frac{21}5 D-\frac {61}5=0$

$N+S=\frac{-21}5$ and $NS=\frac{-61}5$

$N^2+S^2+2NS=(\frac {21} 5)^2=\frac{441}{25}$

$5N^2-21N-61=0$

Summing these relations we get:

$6N^2+3NS+S^2-21N-61=\frac{441}{25}-\frac{61}{5}=\frac{197}{25}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a systematic way.

Consider $P=6N^2 + 3NS + S^2 - 21N -61$ and $A(N)$ as polynomials in $N$. Let $R$ be the remainder of $P$ mod $A(N)$. Now consider $R$ and $A(S)$ as polynomials in $S$. Compute the remainder of $R$ mod $A(S)$. The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialRemainder%5BPolynomialRemainder%5B6+N%5E2+%2B+3+N+S+%2B+S%5E2+-+21+N+-+61%2C+5+N%5E2+-+21+N+-+61%2C+N%5D%2C+5+S%5E2+-+21+S+-+61%2C+S%5D) is
$$
3 NS + 21(N+S)/5 + 122/5
$$
and you can now use Vieta's formulas.